# Linking to Apache v.2.0 software in LGPL v.2.1 project

Tags: license-compatibility, apache-2.0, lgpl, linked-libraries

I am working on an open source project for an academic competition. Our customer requires us to use for our product the LGPL v.2.1. We have to use QR codes in part of our application, and we found different libraries, all licensed under the Apache License v.2.0. I read that the LGPL and the Apache License are incompatible in these versions.

My question is: does the incompatibility applies only when *using* the code from both, or also in using the *library* without touching the source code? That is, can we use an Apache library in an LGPL project, if we use it *as it is*, without incorporating, but just using/linking to it?

Thanks to all who want to answer and help.

Comment: "*I read that the LGPL and the Apache License are incompatible in these versions*": could you link to where you read this?

Comment: Basically everywhere, but I link you to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility , https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html

Comment: That link refers to GPL compatibility, not LGPL compatibility.  I repeat the question.

Comment: You're right, but for what I understood, the FSF tried to make the GPL and the LGPL as similar as they could in the parts in which they do not differ. On the Wikipedia page, in the graph showing the license compatibilities, they are shown in the same node

Comment: I see no graph on the linked Wikipedia page that shows LGPL and GPL on a common node.  If what you're really saying is "*I read everywhere that GPLv2 and Apache2 are incompatible, so I'm assuming that Apache2 and LGPLv2.1 are incompatible*", it would be good to actually say that.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I confused them. Anyway I was refferring to this graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility#/media/File:Floss-license-slide-image.svg , where you can see that Apache license is incompatible with both (in version 2)